# Is this sentence a dependent clause?

Tags: grammar

Not to mention the amazing embellishments that are sure to spark the interest of our well-healed clients: flowers, butterflies, crystals, and feathers.

Comment: It's not a sentence, in the formal sense; merely an utterance. It **could** be a dependent clause if there were anything there for it depend from (though purists would object to capitalizing it).

Comment: It's not really a clause, unless you want to derive it from something like "And I'm not going to mention <`Embellishment`>" or something like that. You could call it a dependent utterance; it's totally dependent for its grammaticality on the previous discourse; in the right context it's perfectly normal, in others it's bizarre.

Comment: Also, I believe that the phrase is meant to be “well-heeled”.

Answer (score 1):

Trick question?  Yes, that is a dependent clause — which by definition means it is not a sentence.